# Good way to get the key of the highest value of a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, max

I'm trying to get the key of the maximum value in the `Dictionary<string, double> results`.

This is what I have so far:

```
double max = results.Max(kvp => kvp.Value);
return results.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == max).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).First();
```

However, since this seems a little inefficient, I was wondering whether there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Is your dictionary supposed to be <double,string> or is that backwards?

Comment: You're right, it's <string,double>. Corrected.

Comment: why do you have a .Select after where?  I'm not that saavy with LINQ, just curious

Comment: @CoffeeAddict the .Select allows him to do "projection" Here, he is converting the KeyValuePair into just a Key. He could have left this part out and just wrote `.First().Key;` to get the key instead.

Comment: @dss539 Ah, a bit late, but you're right. That would be more efficient.

Comment: @ArdaXi Actually, it might only save a few MSIL instructions. I was just trying to explain to CoffeeAddict what your code was doing. It's perfectly fine the way it is. :)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**edit:** .NET 6 introduced a new method
`var max = results.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;`

You should probably use that if you can.

---

I think this is the most readable O(n) answer using standard LINQ.

```
var max = results.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key;
```

edit: explanation for CoffeeAddict

`Aggregate` is the LINQ name for the commonly known functional concept [Fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)

It loops over each element of the set and applies whatever function you provide.
Here, the function I provide is a comparison function that returns the bigger value.
While looping, `Aggregate` remembers the return result from the last time it called my function. It feeds this into my comparison function as variable `l`. The variable `r` is the currently selected element.

So after aggregate has looped over the entire set, it returns the result from the very last time it called my comparison function. Then I read the `.Key` member from it because I know it's a dictionary entry

Here is a different way to look at it [I don't guarantee that this compiles ;) ]

```
var l = results[0];
for(int i=1; i<results.Count(); ++i)
{
    var r = results[i];
    if(r.Value > l.Value)
        l = r;        
}
var max = l.Key;
```

Comment: +1 dss539:  I had an itch in my brain, like there should have been some way to do it with LINQ.  Nice!

Comment: very helpful, I was just wondering how do we know explicitly that `l` is the return value, just for understanding since c# tends to have very clear syntax here I understood something like that was happening but its a little bit obscure. (I came due to a copilot suggestion it gave me the aggregate function and I am glad I looked up since I am going to use `MinBy()`)

Comment: @Barreto lambda syntax offers a shortcut for returning values. It's a bit like python. The value of the last operation in the function is returned to the caller automatically.  `x => 2*x`is the same as `x => return 2*x`

Comment: well i didnt mean the return by lambda i meant the assignment the return to `l`, for example I use the predicates often, `x` being a object on a collection, like a foreach in my understanding. what i dont understand is how/when is the return value of that expression is assigned to the next round variable. is it specific for the `Aggregate` function could you use it in Find function? this is just hypothetical to explain the question, but I will look for documentation referring to this

Comment: @Barreto yes that is just a behavior of the Aggregate function. You have to read the description of any function to learn what it does with the results returned by your lambda

Answer (score 45):

After reading various suggestions, I decided to benchmark them and share the results.

The code tested:

```
// TEST 1

for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
  KeyValuePair<GameMove, int> bestMove1 = possibleMoves.First();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<GameMove, int> move in possibleMoves)
  {
    if (move.Value > bestMove1.Value) bestMove1 = move;
  }
}

// TEST 2

for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
  KeyValuePair<GameMove, int> bestMove2 = possibleMoves.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Value > b.Value ? a : b);
}

// TEST 3

for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
  KeyValuePair<GameMove, int> bestMove3 = (from move in possibleMoves orderby move.Value descending select move).First();
}

// TEST 4

for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
{
  KeyValuePair<GameMove, int> bestMove4 = possibleMoves.OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Value).First();
}
```

The results:

```
Average Seconds Test 1 = 2.6
Average Seconds Test 2 = 4.4
Average Seconds Test 3 = 11.2
Average Seconds Test 4 = 11.2
```

This is just to give an idea of their relative performance.

If your optimizing 'foreach' is fastest, but LINQ is compact and flexible.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to bench it. How are test 3 and 4 any different? They generate the same MSIL don't they?

Comment: I just checked and you are correct, test 3 and 4 produce the same MSIL code :)

Answer (score 14):

You can sort dictionary by using:

- **OrderByDescending** (for **max** value)
  or
- **OrderBy** (for find **min** value).
  Then get **first** element.
  It also help when you need find **second** **max**/**min** element

---

**First max/min value:**
Get dictionary key by **max** value:

```
double max = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;
```

Get dictionary key by **min** value:

```
double min = results.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First().Key;
```

---

**Second max/min value:**
Get dictionary key by second **max** value:

```
double max = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Skip(1).First().Key;
```

Get dictionary key by second **min** value:

```
double min = results.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Skip(1).First().Key;
```

Comment: It seems that `OrderBy` do more computation than what really is needed.

Comment: Yes. Sorting is O(n * log (n)) and min/max element is O(n).

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this isn't a good use for LINQ.  I see 2 full scans of the dictionary using the LINQ solution (1 to get the max, then another to find the kvp to return the string.

You could do it in 1 pass with an "old fashioned" foreach:

```
KeyValuePair<string, double> max = new KeyValuePair<string, double>(); 
foreach (var kvp in results)
{
  if (kvp.Value > max.Value)
    max = kvp;
}
return max.Key;
```

Comment: I know it leads to the same result but I have found this to be more readable: `var max = default(KeyValuePair<string, double>);`

Comment: You are right; the OP had an O(2n) algorithm using see. See my answer for a O(n) using LINQ.

Comment: +1 for reducing the iterations. You should probably initialize max.Value with double.MinValue to ensure you find a max even if it is a negative.

Comment: keep it simple :) classic search algoritims are always available. No need to think it will be hard.

Answer (score 7):

This is a fast method. It is O(n), which is optimal. The only problem I see is that it iterates over the dictionary twice instead of just once.

You can do it iterating over the dictionary once by using [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview).

```
results.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;
```

Comment: `Aggregate` can also be used for the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Little extension method:

```
public static KeyValuePair<K, V> GetMaxValuePair<K,V>(this Dictionary<K, V> source)
    where V : IComparable
{
    KeyValuePair<K, V> maxPair = source.First();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<K, V> pair in source)
    {
        if (pair.Value.CompareTo(maxPair.Value) > 0)
            maxPair = pair;
    }
    return maxPair;
}
```

Then:

`int keyOfMax = myDictionary.GetMaxValuePair().Key;`

Answer (score 3):

Check These out:

```
result.Where(x=>x.Value==result.Values.Max()).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

My version based off the current Enumerable.Max implementation with an optional comparer:

```
    public static TSource MaxValue<TSource, TConversionResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TConversionResult> function, IComparer<TConversionResult> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TConversionResult>.Default;
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        TSource max = default;
        TConversionResult maxFx = default;
        if ( (object)maxFx == null) //nullable stuff
        {
            foreach (var x in source)
            {
                var fx = function(x);
                if (fx == null || (maxFx != null && comparer.Compare(fx, maxFx) <= 0)) continue;
                maxFx = fx;
                max = x;
            }
            return max;
        }

        //valuetypes
        var notFirst = false;
        foreach (var x in source) 
        {
            var fx = function(x);
            if (notFirst)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(fx, maxFx) <= 0) continue;
                maxFx = fx;
                max = x;
            }
            else
            {
                maxFx = fx;
                max = x;
                notFirst = true;
            }
        }
        if (notFirst)
            return max;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
    }
```

Example usage:

```
    class Wrapper
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }    
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMaxValue()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Wrapper>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            dictionary[$"s:{i}"] = new Wrapper{Value = (i % 10) * 10 } ;
        }

        var m = dictionary.Keys.MaxValue(x => dictionary[x].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(m, "s:9");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it in parallel using Interlocked.Exchange for thread safety :)  Keep in mind that Interlocked.Exchange will only work with a reference type.(i.e. a struct or key value pair (unless wrapped in a class) will not work to hold the max value.

Here's an example from my own code:

```
//Parallel O(n) solution for finding max kvp in a dictionary...
ClassificationResult maxValue = new ClassificationResult(-1,-1,double.MinValue);
Parallel.ForEach(pTotals, pTotal =>
{
    if(pTotal.Value > maxValue.score)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref maxValue, new                
            ClassificationResult(mhSet.sequenceId,pTotal.Key,pTotal.Value)); 
    }
});
```

**EDIT (Updated code to avoid possible race condition above):**

Here's a more robust pattern which also shows selecting a min value in parallel.  I think this addresses the concerns mentioned in the comments below regarding a possible race condition:

```
int minVal = int.MaxValue;
Parallel.ForEach(dictionary.Values, curVal =>
{
  int oldVal = Volatile.Read(ref minVal);
  //val can equal anything but the oldVal
  int val = ~oldVal;

  //Keep trying the atomic update until we are sure that either:
  //1. CompareExchange successfully changed the value.
  //2. Another thread has updated minVal with a smaller number than curVal.
  //   (in the case of #2, the update is no longer needed)
  while (oldval > curVal && oldval != val)
  {
    val = oldval;
    oldval = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref minVal, curVal, oldval);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this example has a race condition. Between the time you compare the max value against the current, and swap them, another thread could have done the same thing and already swapped a better value into maxValue that will then be clobbered by the current thread's worse value.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more robust solution which I think addresses the potential race condition.

Comment: I think you're right. That's how I was thinking of resolving the race. I do wonder if a read-write lock would have better performance. +1 for the update

Answer (score -4):

I think using the standard LINQ Libraries this is as fast as you can go.