# At least one object must implement IComparable in Max()

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help me why I got error

> at least one object must implement icomparable

from this below code?

```
item.IndicatorMeasurements
    .OrderBy(a => a.EntryDateRange.ToDateTime)
    .Max()
    .Color;
```

Comment: `ToDateTime` sounds like it's a method.  Are you sure you didn't intend to call the method? (`a => a.EntryDateRange.ToDateTime()`)

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805703/good-way-to-get-the-key-of-the-highest-value-of-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are trying to find the max value of your list of `IndicatorMeasurements`, and the compiler has no idea of how to do that. If you want the object with the newest date, you either implement that interface or, more easily, and if the list is not too long, you can use

`OrderBy(a => a.EntryDateRange.ToDateTime).Last()`

or

`OrderByDescending(a => a.EntryDateRange.ToDateTime).First()`.

If the list is long, you should implement that interface or else use your own method to find the maximum item. Thanks Andrey for the hint.

Comment: BTW, the solution with `OrderBy` is ineffective for finding the maximum value only