# how to read a csv file and display row values and column values

Tags: c#, csv

As I'm a beginner in c# I need help !!! . I have a .csv file containing Students details in following columns, All I need here is based on the highest marks scored by the individuals , I need to get the output as follows:
(/* The data's in csv file are, say may be 100 in each row and column cell */)

**Name ,Maths,Science,English**(header of csv)

Akash,  80,  67  ,  54

Manoj,  64,  56  ,  72

Subas,  78,  84  ,  63

I can do the read operation and displayed the whole line. But my problem is I want to display the Name of the student and subject from the highest score from each subject.

**Sample Output:**

English- Manoj

Maths    - Subas

Science-  Akash

I'm stuck in middle and any answers without using VB are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your requirement description matches with the sample output. Here is the code to get each subject and the student with the highest grade in which.

```
List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(csvText))
{
    while (sr.Peek() > 0)
    {
        data.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(','));
    }
}

//Iterates through columns, skipping first one (names)
List<string> output = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i < data[0].Count(); i++)
{
    string subjectName = data[0][i];
    Dictionary<string,int> grades = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    //Iterates through rows, skipping first one (headers)
    for (int j = 1; j < data.Count; j++)
    {
        grades.Add(data[j][0],Convert.ToInt32(data[i][j]));
    }
    output.Add(subjectName + " - " + grades.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key);
}
```

Credit to answers in this question for the Aggregate linq: [Get key of highest value in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805703/good-way-to-get-the-key-of-the-highest-value-of-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks a lot Thor !!!... I'm i guess it is possible.... First i had the idea of taking the names column alone in a List<string> , later for numerical i thought of taking the marks column in List<int>... Finally i put on the logic part of getting the highest mark and name... Anyways thanks for the help :D

Comment: By all means include your solution here as well so others can pick the one that tickles their fancy.